# error on second foreach loop in php

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

i have an array containing query results to wordpress db:

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id, user_login, date, data1, data2 FROM table WHERE date >= 'date1' AND date <= 'date2'");
foreach ($query as $a) {
    $array[] = array('id'=>$a->id, 'user_login'=>$a->user_login, 'date'=>$a->date, 'data1'=>$a->data1, 'data2'=>$a->data2);
}
```

next foreach loop to make strings for my needs i'm getting nothing, even

```
foreach ($array as $c) {
    $d = $c->id;
}
echo $d;
```

returns Null. what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($array)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$c` is an array not an object.

Try `$d = $c["id"];`

Answer (score 1):

Wrong

```
$d = $c->id;
```

Right

```
$d = $c["id"];
```